# Retrieving data from a shared data extension with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I have a hard time figuring out how to adjust the code mentioned below to read data from a shared data extension.

Some details about the situation:

- The script is executed from a child business unit
- In the current shape the `rows` variable is `undefined` which means the code failed to retrieve data.
- The code reads the correct number of rows when I change the location to make the data extension non-shared (and the `sourceDE = "ContentDE"`)
- I've tried the following values for `sourceDE`:

  - `"ENT.ContentDE"`
  - `"[MID].ContentDE"`
  - `"ContentDE"` (though this should work in the root business unit)
- No error is being caught even if I put a non-existent DE name

Any idea how to format the data extension name or if something needs to be added to the `RetrieveRequest` object to read a shared data extension?

---

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.5");

var sourceDE = "ENT.ContentDE';

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[" + sourceDE + "]");

Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "id");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "column_1");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "column_2");

try {
    do {
        var results = [0,0];
        var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
        var runstatus = results[0];
        var requestId = results[1];
        Write("Numbers of rows read: " + rows.length);
        rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;
    } while (runstatus == "MoreDataAvailable");
} catch (error) {
    Write(Stringify(error))
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wolsztniak - did you find the solution?